# How wiegand reader only read the 24 bit?

Tags: gpio

H10301 is the HID standard wiegand 26 format where preprogrammed to have 2 parity bits, 8 bits facility code and 16 bits card number.

My question is, how do wiegand device convert a 40 bit ID into wiegand protocol where in fact it doesn't have parity bit at all?

EG. 48454C4C4F is the id, this has 40 bit. But when converted into wiegand protocol it gave 4C4548. (4C is the FC and 4548 is the Card Number, Wiegand reader was set to MSB first). I noticed wiegand reader truncates the ID into 24 bit, so where is the parity bit?

Does the parity bit was automated by the reader?

Any information was greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Wiegand codes can use an arbitrary number of bits.

The Wiegand bits are complete when a timeout expires on both the green (0) and white (1) data bit lines.

In a particular application a fixed number of bits would probably be used.

The bits can be formatted and have any meaning as chosen by the application developer (unless constrained to meet an external standard).

Comment: Thanks @Joan, But if wiegand needs 26 bit (standard), where did the parity came from if the reader truncated it to only just 24 bit?

Comment: @user7040804 The reader software would likely discard any check bits once the check has been done.  You would need to inspect the reader software or its specs.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the wiegand reader was connected to an access controller. So basically, software are somewhat not involved here, 'cause, the wiegand reader converts the data sent from the card to wiegand protocol, then access controller validates the data. And my question is, where does the parity came from?Thanks. :)